# onCreateOptionsMenu is already defined

Tags: java, android, menu, menuitem

I want to make my *menu items* clickable in order to open other activity (further maybe activities). I have two menu xml files. One of them main.xml which I have already define in *MainActivity.java*, and it is working. But then I added another menu with items (as navigation bar). So, I have tried to define this in MainActivity.java too. But it gives me error on  *'onCreateOptionsMenu()'* and *'onOptionsItemSelcted()'*. Yes, maybe it is weird to use them twice. But then how should I define my second menu with it's items?

**MainActivity.java (piece of code):**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_categories:
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(r_nav)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(r_nav);
                }
                else if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(r_nav)) {
                    drawer.openDrawer(r_nav);
                }
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(navigationView);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu_item_categ) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.categories_navigation, menu_item_categ);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu_item_categ);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.m_item_avto_qismlar) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_homashyo) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_kitob) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_kanstovar) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_libos) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_texnika) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_mebel) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_ovqat) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_materiallar) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_tekstil) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.m_item_uskunalar) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity_ombor.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

*main.xml (menu. I am using it in order to put icon to the action bar where by clicking I could call navigation menu)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_categories"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_categories"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

*categories_navigation.xml (menu. Here I am trying to act with items to call another activity. See above MainActivity.java)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="Bo'limlar">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_avto_qismlar"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_011_car_repair"
                    android:title="Avto-ehtiyot qismlar" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_homashyo"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_002_block"
                    android:title="Homashyolar" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_kitob"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_009_agenda"
                    android:title="Kitoblar" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_kanstovar"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_008_stationery"
                    android:title="Kanstovarlar" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_libos"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_007_dress"
                    android:title="Liboslar" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_texnika"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_006_transport"
                    android:title="Maxsus texnika" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_mebel"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_005_sofa"
                    android:title="Mebellar" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_ovqat"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_004_apple"
                    android:title="Oziq-ovqat mahsulotlari" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_materiallar"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_003_tools"
                    android:title="Qurilish materiallari" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_tekstil"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_010_ball_of_wool"
                    android:title="Tekstil mahsulotlari" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/m_item_uskunalar"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_001_conveyor"
                    android:title="Uskunalar" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: You can't have 2 menus. Put it all in one menu

Comment: You can not use duplicate methods its simple java . Why you need such thing?

Comment: @ADM Because I have two menu xml files.

Comment: @Vucko Why should I put if I have two separate menu xml file? Could you show it with example?

Comment: You cannot inflate two menus mate. Put it all in one `menu.xml` file. Copy items from one to the other, simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I uploaded the question I was beginner. If you met with like that situation, you can just create a button and then create a menu. When you click to the button the menu will be opened. It means, you don't need create two menus if which one contains only one item anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have on onCreateOptionsMenu and only one onOptionsItemSelected in your Activity class. To change your menu dynamically use invalidateOptionsMenu(); whenever you want to change it and override this method to update your menu

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am new in android. I tried what you wrote, but it is not working. Maybe I did not catch it. Could you show it with my above code?

Comment: how are you planning to use two menus, there is place for only one. How do you want them in UI

Comment: I have one main.xml menu. Which i defined to open and close navigation bar. The second categories_navigation.xml menu I am trying to define that navigation menu's items, where I can click them and call another activity. In other words in UI I have only one menu. Why I am using main.xml menu, because that I could use to put to the action bar as icon, instead of tree dots appearance

Comment: why dont you use navigation drawer instead?

Comment: I have already used navigation drawer on the left side. In tutorial one guy show how to create two navigation drawer. One he made by navigation drawer itself, another one as I showed above. So, anyway there should be a way to solve above problem. But I can't find it..

Comment: you don't need to override any method for using a menu with your navigation drawer, you can directly set the menu to your navigation drawer, you can also have two navigation drawers in a single activity but you cannot have more than one options menu, obviously you can change contents at runtime but you cannot have two menus